# How to get the shortest cyclic path in a Graph?

Tags: java, traversal

I am developing a simple program to calculate the shortest path from one city to other, using directed weighted nodes of a graph to represent a train trail map.

So far I tried `Bellman-Ford`, `Dijkstra`, `Floyd-Warshall` and `Johnson` algorithms and all of them are good to find the shortest path to a different destination which is not the same as the start.

But when I need to calculate the path between city A and back to city A through other cities, I always get 0 value because those methods ignore the path from a city to itself in order to don't get caught in an infinity loop.

I know that it might be simple to resolve that loop problem by creating another parameter which is `target` to aim the algorithm to stop when it catches this *target* node, but I don't have the skill to modify one of those libraries.

Can anyone show me the way?

My graph is `AB5 - BC4 - CD8 - DC8 - DE6 - AD5 - CE2 - EB3 - AE7` and the distance from `B` to `B` should be `9`, but in all those algorithms it's returning `0`.

*Note: it's not a duplicate, since nobody bothered so far on finding routes at ends at the beginning, as I searched on StackOverflow and Google, at least in Java.*

Comment: Probably you mean a [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: algorithms you have tried are meant to find the shortest distance between two edges of a graph. see TSP as @MichaelButscher mentioned.

Comment: With a distance of 9 from B to B (using edges BC, CE and EB) the OP wants to solve the [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) (between nodes), which is exactly what [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and co are for!

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain the Dijkstra code that I have do not consider cyclic paths.

Comment: @EASI, If you are looking for the shortest path then it won't contain any cycle. Formally the shortest path from B to B is the empty path (you are already in B right?). One way to "emulate" what you want to compute is to duplicate each nodes as explained on my answer.

Comment: hehehe, I am anxious to see which will be the excuse to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use the shortest path algorithms/libraries that you already have with a modified graph. You could duplicate each node and the corresponding adjacent outgoing edges, and then find the shortest path from the duplicated node to the original one.

Here is how the transformation would look like for A-A path (without weight for simplicity):

[image: Graphical example]